# adding datasource to a Jdbctemplate bean throws exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I'm trying to learn spring and bean configuration.

I'm going to have several classes that are gonna DB related functions so each one of them is gonna need to have a JdbcTemplate class. because of that I want to create a bean configuration that will inject a singleton JdbcTemplate class to each one of my DB related classes.

I created the following bean configuration.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo"/>  
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="password"></property>  
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
     <property name="initialSize" value="5" />  
</bean>   

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" scope="singleton">
 <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg> 
</bean>
```

the problem starts when I add the `constructor-args` parameter to the jdbcTemplate. jdbctemplate needs to receive the datasource as a parameter to it's constructor. but when I add that property and I try to execute my application this is the exception that I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:112)
org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:85)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

what am I missing ?

thank you!

Comment: Your output does not match `context.xml`. No bean named 'dataSource2' is defined

Comment: ooops I copied the wrong exception!!! fixing it

Comment: This is problem with classpath

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758151/class-conflict-when-starting-up-java-project-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-in

Comment: "the problem starts when I add the constructor-args parameter to the jdbcTemplate. jdbctemplate needs to receive the datasource as a parameter to it's constructor. but when I add that property and I try to execute my application this is the exception that I'm getting:" Did you mean it comes when you add
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> Or when 
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>

Comment: <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>

Comment: @Grzegorz: i wish I noticed your comment sooner. this resolved my issue! post it as answer and i'll accept it :) thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try code if you want jdbcTemplate

```
 <!-- DataSource configuration for Apache Commons DBCP. -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

 <!--jdcb template for DB tests-->
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that there is a jdbcTemplate tyring to reference a dataSource called "dataSource2"... but you have defined one called "dataSource"

Check all the spring context files in your application for a jdbc template that looks like:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" scope="singleton">
 <constructor-arg ref="dataSource2"></constructor-arg> 
</bean>
```

Perhaps you have accidently declared two. If not try refreshing project, clean etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Bean.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="customerDAO" class="com.shreyansh.dao.impl.JdbcCustomerDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Spring-Datasource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shreyansh" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Spring-Module.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <import resource="database/Spring-Datasource.xml" />
    <import resource="customer/Spring-Customer.xml" />

</beans>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i didn't quite understand it. where is jdbctemplate here ?

Answer (score 0):

As seeing yours error 
**java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError** .This is thrown 
 when an incompatible class change has occurred to some class 
 definition.So,it seems like versions problem .Would you tell which versions of java ,spring and system are you using.

Comment: spring 3.2.3 system is linux gentoo. tomcat 7.0.39

Comment: java version "1.7.0_09" IcedTea7 2.3.3