# IS CAS 4.0.0 compatible with spring

Tags: spring, cas

Currently we are migrating spring old version to 4.0.0. Also we o upgraded CAS 4.0.0.

Now we are getting

> 8 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /security/login: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]

Comment: possible duplicate of [IncompatibleClassChangeError: class ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface ClassVisitor as super class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209623/incompatibleclasschangeerror-class-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-interface-cl)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209623/incompatibleclasschangeerror-class-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-interface-cl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758151/class-conflict-when-starting-up-java-project-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-in