# IncompatibleClassChangeError:org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface *.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-management

I am using Spring 4.1 and writing maven modules from scratch. I have 2 service modules A and B and a webapp which makes calls to service A whose implementation is there in module B. Following is the list of Spring jars in my parent pom.

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.version}</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

I got few more issues before encountering this which i resolved. So one of the posts asked to put the below dependencies as well (I dont understand why i have to provide it if spring needed them why its not packaged with it).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${aspect.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspect.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I got the mentioned issue and one of the posts suggests to exclude the spring-asm which is old and include latest asm-all dependency.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>asm</groupId>
     <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I removed spring-asm dependency add the above. Now i run into the issue where the classes are not compatible. Kindly suggest how can i resolve it.

My complete tree is:

```
    --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ testapp ---
com.name:testapp:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
+- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
|     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
+- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:provided
+- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:provided
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:provided
+- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:provided
+- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:provided
+- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.0.RELEASE:provided
+- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4:provided
+- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4:provided
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
+- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
+- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
+- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
+- com.name:MongoClient-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.12.3:compile
|  \- com.name:GenericException:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
\- com.name:MongoClient-Impl:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out your dependencies remove all dependencies to old Spring jars especially `spring-asm` jar. You don't need asm as a dependency as it is inlined in `spring-core` as of Spring 3.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IncompatibleClassChangeError: class ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface ClassVisitor as super class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209623/incompatibleclasschangeerror-class-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-interface-cl) and [Class Conflict when starting up Java project: ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758151/class-conflict-when-starting-up-java-project-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-in)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have included only spring-core and tried nogo and also added spring-web as suggested still issue persists.

Comment: As I stated in my first comment. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see where the `spring-asm` dependency is coming from and exclude it. (That is also mentioned in the other threads with the same problem).

Comment: The only asm dependency is asm-all which i included but now i have removed it as you suggest in your first comment. Issue persists. Here is my complete tree

Comment: Please add the tree to your post.

Comment: thank you very much my issue got resolved as i removed it from the container which i had added.

Comment: That either isn't your full tree or the spring-asm jar is somewhere in your path that you, currently , don't know about. What I find strange is why on earth are your spring dependencies scoped provided? Yuor test dependency should have test scope but that is compile. To me it looks like that you have an old version of spring somewhere on your server and that you are now mixing versions.

Comment: IncompatibleClassChangeError means that code was compiled with one version of a referenced class and is being run with a different version.  If the classes involved are library modules that means you have incompatible jar files.  With a little research (examine jar contents) you can determine which jar files those are.