# Spring boot: InvocationTargetException Solr

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, solr

I am trying to build a spring boot/data/solr application.  Using STS 3.6.4 no compile errors but when I run `mvn clean spring-boot:run` I get this exception:

```
>     Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE:run
> (default-cli) on project search: An exception occured while running.
> null: InvocationTargetException: Failed to read candidate component
> class: file
> [/Users/griff/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE/SearchEng_Proto/target/classes/com/foo/search/config/SolrContext.class];
> nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError:
> Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class
> org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.EnableSolrRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
> -> [Help 1]
>     [ERROR]
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit :[Class Conflict when starting up Java project: ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758151/class-conflict-when-starting-up-java-project-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-in)

The problem is the order of library in pom, use gradle (if you can) is more simple.

The founded solution is:
**"i resolved the same problem by reordering the pom dependencies.
i got issue from org.springframework.security. so i brought it to end of the dependencies."**

Comment: Kindly add the important part as the answer  instead of putting a link.