# MethodReplace not working in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm trying to replace a calcInt method in Bank class with a new method 
in a new Class NewCalcInt.java. But I'm not able to do that. Help me to
solve this. I have added all the JAR's along with cglib-nodep-2.1.3 jar.

This is the following code
Bank.java

```
package beans;

 public class Bank {
     public void deposit() {
         System.out.println("Deposit Method in Bank");
     }
     public void withdraw() {
         System.out.println("Withdraw Method in Bank");
     }
     public void calcInt() {
         System.out.println("CalcInt Method in Bank");
     }
 }
```

The following program is NewCalcInt.java

NewCalcInt.java

```
package beans;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.MethodReplacer;

 public class NewCalcInt implements MethodReplacer {
    public Object reimplement(Object o, Method m, Object[] arg2) throws
    Throwable {

        System.out.println("NewCalcInt class new CalInt imp");
        return o;
    }
}
```

The following code is spring.xml
spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd" >
    <bean id="b" class="beans.Bank">
        <replaced-method name="calcInt" replacer="nc"></replaced-method>
    </bean>
    <bean id="nc" class="beans.NewCalcInt"></bean>
</beans>
```

The following code is ClientApp.java
ClientApp.java

```
 package beans;

 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

 public class ClientApp {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
         Bank b = (Bank) context.getBean("b");
         b.deposit();
         b.withdraw();
         b.deposit();
     }
 }
```

I have already add the JARs

Comment: It seems no problem, can you try to place `<bean id="nc" class="beans.NewCalcInt">` at first?

Comment: @Mavlarn I tried but no change in the run time. I will show u the errors WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'b' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'b' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item, Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

Comment: So the definition is wrong, check this:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/MethodReplacementExample.htm

Comment: Error seems to be coming from incompatible cglib, try using cglib 3.x. That might solve your problem. and check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758151/class-conflict-when-starting-up-java-project-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-in

Comment: @Mavlarn I used the correct definition. I just don't understand what exact JAR's are needed. did I include any extra JARs from spring directory. tell me what JARs do I need to include in that program

Comment: @kuhajeyan I tried both cglib 2.1.3 and 3.1 but no change in the output. tell me what exact JAR's do I need to include in that program. did I include any extra JARs from spring directory

Comment: @kuhajeyan I removed some of the JARs which I included and now its working fine.

Comment: good, that. may be you share what you did , that could help someone.